# Change WooCommerce stock quantity text based on Product Tags and Product Variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

I'm looking how for a woocommerce custom stock quantity tekst based on tags, that is working with variable products, back-orders and stock mangament with the following parameters:

If a product has a specific product tag, I would like to change the "instock" text to 'Stock: ' . $stock. ' pieces. Shipping in 2-3 days' and the "out of stock" text to 'Not on stock, delivery time 20 to 25 working days."

This should work with single products, and variable products on the same time on which back-orders and stock management is enabled. I have at certain products more than 230 variables. As in product: ****

I have tried the following test, and it was working on single products.
However on variation level, the products with 1 random tag and the 1101, the line of the 1104 tag gets displayed.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'woo_cust_stock_quantity_text', 99, 2 );

function woo_cust_stock_quantity_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();


    if ( has_term( 1100 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 20 t/m 25 werkdagen voor chroom, 40 t/m 60 werkdagen voor kleur.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1101 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 20 t/m 25 werkdagen voor chroom, 40 t/m 60 werkdagen voor kleur.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1102 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 20 t/m 25 werkdagen voor chroom, 40 t/m 60 werkdagen voor Mat-zwart.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1103 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 1 t/m 5 werkdagen.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1104 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 4 t/m 7 werkdagen.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1105 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 7 t/m 14 werkdagen.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1106 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 3 tot 5 weken.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1107 , 'product_tag' ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 8 tot 12 weken.';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

I have tried a lot, but my knowledge is not too deep into PHP to figure it out.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: Since its variable product each variation should have its own stock qty so i would recommend check first what type of product we are dealing with then separate your logic for simple and variable products. For variable products you have to use ajax since when we select specific variation the qty will be different etc..

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you very much for your reply. Thye are variable products as set up in here: https://luxekranen.nl/product/daniel-smart-green-inbouw-bidetmengkraan-15-kleuren-25119108f-15k/ with their stock mangement enabled. Not downloadable or virtual products. Please let me know if you require more information. Br. Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WooCommerce Custom taxonomies like product categories or product tags are not managed by Product Variations, but by their **parent** Variable Product. Then I have revisited your code a bit to make it work with Product variations too:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'woo_cust_stock_quantity_text', 99, 2 );
function woo_cust_stock_quantity_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $stock      = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    // Getting the parent product Id for product variations
    $product_id = ( $product->get_type() == 'variation' ) ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if ( has_term( 1100 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 20 t/m 25 werkdagen voor chroom, 40 t/m 60 werkdagen voor kleur.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1101 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 20 t/m 25 werkdagen voor chroom, 40 t/m 60 werkdagen voor kleur.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1102 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 20 t/m 25 werkdagen voor chroom, 40 t/m 60 werkdagen voor Mat-zwart.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1103 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 1 t/m 5 werkdagen.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1104 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 4 t/m 7 werkdagen.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1105 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 7 t/m 14 werkdagen.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1106 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 3 tot 5 weken.';
    }
    if ( has_term( 1107 , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
       if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Voorraad: ' . $stock. ' stuks. Verwachte levertijd 8 tot 12 weken.';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for you code! :) I've tried it, but WPCode is automaticly deactivating the snippet due an error in it. Are your sure it is correct?

Comment: @RenéR Sorry There was a missing ";" at the end of a code line that was the guilty... Try it now again.